# Converting a Advanced REST Client request to scala code

Tags: scala

I was able to successfully request using Advanced REST client. In the ARC, I used below config

1. The URL is as "https://url"
2. header: content-type as application/xml
3. header: user-agent as uid
4. header: authorization as Basic

   1. The value was created by supplying the uid and pwd
5. body: as xml

With below scala code the output is, "Exception:java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem"

```
import gigahorse.{ AuthScheme, Gigahorse, MimeTypes }

val request = Gigahorse
  .url("https://<url>").post(xml)
  .withAuth("<uid>", "<pwd>", AuthScheme.Basic)
  .withContentType(MimeTypes.XML, Gigahorse.utf8)
  .withRequestTimeout(5000.millis)
val client = SSLManager(None, None, "TLSv1").createSSLHttpClient
val resp = client.run(request)
resp.onComplete({
  case Success(listInt) => {
    log.info(s"Result:${listInt}")
  }
  case Failure(exception) => {
    log.info(s"Exception:${exception}")
  }
})
```

What is wrong with this code?

The full exception:

```
[error] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416)
[error]     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1392)
[error]     at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1255)
[error]     ... 18 more
[error] Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
[error]     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
[error]     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
[error]     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)
[error]     ... 26 more
[error] Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
[error]     at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
[error]     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
[error]     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
```

Comment: First of all which implementation are you using - `gigahorse-okhttp`, `gigahorse-asynchttpclient` or `gigahorse-akka-http` ? And which version? Also please include the whole stack trace of Exception instead of just the message line.

Comment: I am using gigahorse-core v0.1.1

Comment: Where is this `SSLManager` coming from ?

Comment: I think that ARC, like Postman, is a bit relaxed with SSL validation, or at least can be configured to be relaxed with certificates. Java default behaviour otoh is quite strict, and as it says, it's failing to validate that there's a valid certificate for the given URL. Check in ARC with strict mode if possible ?